# Implement Generic function in angular component

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to use a generic function instead 3 function on my Angular Component, these functions do the same task, update the values of property in the same object, my original functions are:

```
    updateRoomPayload(container: RoomBooking) {
        this.scoreCard.room_booking = container;
    }

    updateUpsellingPayload(container: Upsellings) {
        this.scoreCard.p_upselling = container;
    }

    updateCateringPayload(container: Catering) {
        this.scoreCard.p_catering = container;
    }
```

I'm geting the update from the output of a child component like this:

```
<app-rooms
    [optionsLists]="catalogue"
    (roomPayload)="updateRoomPayload($event)"
></app-rooms>
```

My generic function is:

```
updatePayload<T>(container: T) {
        switch ((typeof container).toString()) {
            case 'RoomBooking':
                this.scoreCard.room_booking = container;
                break;

            case 'Upsellings':
                this.scoreCard.p_upselling = container;
                break;

            case 'Catering':
                this.scoreCard.p_catering = container;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

But I found that `(typeof container).toString()` only get me type of this var is object but I can't check if it is instance of a specific object, how could I get type of the object?

my interfaces are:

```
export interface RoomBooking {
    room_type?: optionScore[];
    nights?: scoreRanges[];
    advance_booking?: scoreRanges[];
    contrated_price_n?: scoreRanges[];
    cancellation_policy?: optionScore[];
    meal_plan?: optionScore[];
}

export interface Upsellings {
    service_type?: optionScore[];
    n_upselling_bought?: scoreRanges[];
    n_cross_upselling_bought?: scoreRanges[];
    amount_upselling?: scoreRanges[];
}

export interface Catering {
    product_category?: optionScore[];
    avg_time?: scoreRanges[];
    advance_booking?: scoreRanges[];
}

export interface Scorecard {
    _id?: string;
    create_at?: string;
    update_at?: string;
    p_recurrence?: scoreRanges[];
    room_booking?: RoomBooking;
    p_upselling?: Upsellings;
    p_catering?: Catering;
}
```

Comment: I would pass the type of container as a second parameter. It could be a string or even an enum. There's no simple way for you to get the type of interface that is being passed as a generic value.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that there was an easy way to catch it

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
updatePayload<T>(container: T) {
        switch (container.constructor.name) {
            case 'RoomBooking':
                this.scoreCard.room_booking = container;
                break;

            case 'Upsellings':
                this.scoreCard.p_upselling = container;
                break;

            case 'Catering':
                this.scoreCard.p_catering = container;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
}
```

It should work!

Comment: it doesn't work the value of `container.constructor.name` is 'Object'